# Unenhanced performance of matlab GPU computing

Tags: performance, matlab, cuda, gpu

With the intention of comparing the speed of GPU vs CPU computing, I ran the example codes available [here](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2011/07/18/a-mandelbrot-set-on-the-gpu/) (a Mandelbrot set on the GPU) from MATLAB central.  Below are the results that I obtained:

- Case 1 (without GPU): 6.2 secs
- Case 2 (using parallel.gpu.GPUArray): 6.518 secs (1.39 secs in the example)
- Case 3 (Using Element-wise Operation): 1.259 secs (0.14 secs in the example)

As can be seen, there is no improvement in case 2 and only slight improvement of around 4 times in case 3. As the example did not state the details of GPU they used, may I know if this is simply due to the "incompetency" of my graphic card or am I missing something important?

The graphic card is also responsible for driving my display (HP Z Display Z23i 23-inch IPS LED Backlit Monitor).

CPU: Intel i7-4790, 3.6 GHz (8 cores)

GPU:

```
                  Name: 'NVS 510'
                 Index: 1
     ComputeCapability: '3.0'
        SupportsDouble: 1
         DriverVersion: 6
        ToolkitVersion: 5
    MaxThreadsPerBlock: 1024
      MaxShmemPerBlock: 49152
    MaxThreadBlockSize: [1024 1024 64]
           MaxGridSize: [2.1475e+09 65535 65535]
             SIMDWidth: 32
           TotalMemory: 2.1475e+09
            FreeMemory: 1.6934e+09
   MultiprocessorCount: 1
          ClockRateKHz: 797000
           ComputeMode: 'Default'
  GPUOverlapsTransfers: 1
KernelExecutionTimeout: 1
      CanMapHostMemory: 1
       DeviceSupported: 1
        DeviceSelected: 1
```

Thank you!

**Edit**

The GPU used in the example [here](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2011/07/18/a-mandelbrot-set-on-the-gpu/) is Tesla C2050. (Credits to @Sam Roberts)

Comment: I worked with Ben Tordoff at the time he wrote the article you link to. If I remember correctly, he was using a Tesla C2050, which for the time (2011) was pretty high-end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The times on that link are most likely for a different GPU in comparison to yours.  They don't specify what kind of graphics card they're using, but my guess is that they're using a more higher end card.

By Googling `NVS 510`, the specs are similar to the card that I have for my machine.  However, your card is geared towards business while mine is geared towards gaming.  I have a GTX 660 which is one of the higher end GPUs that are available on the market.

These are the attributes of my graphics card:

```
CUDADevice with properties:

                  Name: 'GeForce GTX 660'
                 Index: 1
     ComputeCapability: '3.0'
        SupportsDouble: 1
         DriverVersion: 6.5000
        ToolkitVersion: 5.5000
    MaxThreadsPerBlock: 1024
      MaxShmemPerBlock: 49152
    MaxThreadBlockSize: [1024 1024 64]
           MaxGridSize: [2.1475e+09 65535 65535]
             SIMDWidth: 32
           TotalMemory: 2.1475e+09
            FreeMemory: 1.5357e+09
   MultiprocessorCount: 5
          ClockRateKHz: 1084500
           ComputeMode: 'Default'
  GPUOverlapsTransfers: 1
KernelExecutionTimeout: 1
      CanMapHostMemory: 1
       DeviceSupported: 1
        DeviceSelected: 1
```

The differences between my card and yours are that I have 5 multiprocessors, and my clock rate is about 300 MHz faster than yours.  For a side-by-side comparison, check out my card in comparison to yours:

- `NVS 510`: http://www.nvidia.ca/object/nvs-510-graphics-card.html#pdpContent=2
- `GTX 660`: http://www.geforce.com/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-gtx-660/specifications

Upon further inspection, I have a much higher memory bandwidth than your card.  I also have 960 GPU cores in comparison to your 192.

I decided to run these tests to compare my performance with your timings.  My CPU is an i7-4770 3.6 GHz Intel and I have 16 GB of RAM on my machine.

The times that I get by running those examples are the following:

- Case #1 - Without GPU: 6.46 seconds
- Case #2 - Naive GPU: 0.82 seconds - 7.9x faster
- Case #3 - Through CUDA: 0.09 seconds - 71.7x faster

---

With this, my guess is that your graphics card may be of a lower quality in comparison to those tests that MathWorks performed.  Maybe try updating your graphics drivers and see if that helps.  However, my guess is that my performance is much better due to the multiprocessor count, faster clock, a higher amount of cores and higher memory bandwidth.

Comment: I see. I chose this graphic card because it has a compute capability (cc) of '3.0'. From our results, even both cards have the same cc scores, they differ so much. So I guess 'compute capability' can't really served as buying guide for matlab GPU computing purposes. Thank you for your informative comparison!

Comment: Add on: I modified the code in case2 to exclude the data transferring time (place 'gpuArray' and 'gather' outside of tic toc) and found that the results are almost the same with those in my question above. So I guess we can filter out memory bandwidth and attribute the most probable causes to "higher multiprocessor count, faster clock and higher amount of cores".

Comment: @user3237120 - I totally understand what you mean.  I made the same mistake before where I thought that the compute capability would be enough, but the physical hardware specifications were not enough for what I needed.  You're most welcome!  I'm sorry that this wasn't what you wanted to hear, but at least you know why your performance isn't the same in comparison to your card.  Good luck!

Comment: "Compute Capability" describes the general features of the GPU: for example: instruction set, double precision support, dynamic kernel dispatch, etc.  As you've discovered, each compute capability (roughly related to the generation of the product) is released in a wide range of actual GPUs, where what varies is: number of multiprocessors, clock rate, and amount and speed of memory.  They do this to control price and power.

Comment: One more note regarding memory bandwidth: Yes, time to copy data across PCI Express matters, but that's not what is usually meant by "memory bandwidth".  Once the data is on the GPU, the speed at which it can be fetched from GPU memory to the GPU core is often the limiting factor, rather than ops/second in the core.  This is why the data flow structure of your kernel is so important, and why cache settings can make a huge difference.

Comment: @Peter, thank you for the information! Taking matlab R2013b as example, is it possible to edit the cache settings to improve my current performance?

Comment: Assuming the GPU code is well-written, no.  Cache settings and usage are part of the compiled GPU code.  This comment was just to indicate that the memory bus width and speed is just as important as the GPU number of cores.  A great deal of the CUDA programming guide is devoted to the best way to structure your kernels to make use the complicated memory hierarchy available in the hardware.  Chances are, the code you're using already pays attention to this stuff, and what you get is what you get.